# How to prevent ActionBar items get hidden when Navigation Drawer opens?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

I have implemented Navigation Drawer with `ActionBar` which has only one item which opens the navigation drawer. So both the Home and menu item buttons open the drawer.  And all works fine with no crashes.

But when I click on the `ActionBar` Home button or menu item, the Navigation drawer opens and **menu item becomes invisible**.

How can I prevent this? I want it be always visible, regardless if drawer is open or closed.

I tried multiple solutions already. For example, in the drawer class, method `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` is called in `onCreate`. Then I set menu item to be present `always`.

Then in the main `Activity`, I tried to capture the menu item during the creation

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    try {
        MenuItem item = menu.getItem(0);
        if (item != null) {
            item.setVisible(true);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

but when drawer appears, the `menu` object return with 0 items.

I am out of ideas.

**EDIT**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) 
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        restoreActionBar();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

public void restoreActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (item != null && id == android.R.id.home) {
        if (mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT)) {
            mNavigationDrawerFragment.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
        } else {
            mNavigationDrawerFragment.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
        }
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

This is RIGHT-SIDE Navigation drawer.

Comment: what does your `onCreateOptionsMenu` look like

Comment: @tyczj Check it now. I edited the question.

Comment: well there you go, you do something special when the drawer opens. or not open I sould say

Comment: @tyczj Do you mean `restoreActionBar` method? I copied it as well.

Comment: no i mean your if statement with `!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()`

Comment: OMG!!! I haven't even seen this IF. It came by default and it was hidden by a comment from Google developers. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is your problem

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) 
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        restoreActionBar();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

you dont have a menu when the drawer opens, remove that if statement